# How to run python app on server through browser

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

I just started using PYTHON and now i want to run a google vision cloud app on the server but I'm not sure how to start. 
I do have a server up and running at http://18.217.137.107 and the app source code looks like https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-landmarks#vision-landmark-detection-python.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will need a web application framework such as django / flask. The url you have linked, only has a python snippet.

Comment: @doubleo I installed flask and everything is working fine I'm able to get results on console via ssh but I want to print the results on a web page. On console I can connect to my database and loop through images and display the result labels but I need to post those results on a web page with html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a webapp built on some framework like django/flask. You can find a basic app example in the following link:
[Create a basic GCP app using Flask](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-web-app-using-pythons-flask-and-google-app-engine-52b1bb82b221/)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [this](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-storage) documentation about deploying Python application using Cloud Storage to App Engine Flex. Also, you might find [this](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/make-an-http-request-to-the-cloud-vision-api-from-java) documentation to make an HTTP Request to Google Cloud Vision API useful, but this is based on Java and not Python.